# C# dataset and DbNull values

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2008

I've a general question - Lets say I've an SQL Server 2008 DB , and it has some nullable columns. Some of these are null and some are not.

Next, I query the DB for a DataRow in C#.

What value would these null fields have in the DataRow object? 
I'm seeing that they have C# "null" values, but someone here said that DbNull != C# null....

Please explain...
thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DBNull.Value` which is not the same as `null`.

[DBNull.Value Field (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)

Comment: What would happen if I were to write row.Field1.trim() for example?

Comment: @Roey - My guess is an InvalidCastException because you can't cast DBNull.Value to string.

Answer (score 2):

With untyped datasets (in DataRow), you can test like this: `DbNull.Value.Equals(dataRow["column"])`

With typed datasets, for nullable columns, there are `IsNull` methods generated, e.g.
`myTypedDataRow.IsMyColumnNull()` which by default you should test before trying to access actual `myTypedDataRow.MyColumn` value, because if it has a null value, it would throw an exception. This behavior can be changed by setting column's `NullValue` property in DataSet Designer.